# Can't see content of VCS changes tab in YouTrack?

Tags: bitbucket, youtrack

I have linked a YouTrack server installation with a BitBucket repository. YouTrack can access the repository because it lets me choose the repository I want to track. However, when I make a commit , there is no content in the VCS changes tab, although something is happening because the number that appears in the tab that indicates the number of vcs changes get updated.
[image: VCS changes tab show empty but number of changes appears]

The user I am logged in with has permissions to see the issue(I can see it all the information but the VCS changes)

Comment: Most likely [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-32712).

Comment: You were right, the solution was to download a later build of the 6.5 version

Comment: a later build of the 6.5 version? Do you mean older? I'm on this version, and have this problem, which, at the moment, is the latest.

JetBrains Bug & Issue Tracker YouTrack 6.5
Build 17006 [12-01-2016 21:35]

Comment: Yes , I mean older. I solved the problem by updating to the the build 17015. Check the link provided by @DanielB for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution: it was a bug of the first builds of the 6.5 version. To avoid it, you have to download the latest version 6.5.17015

Comment: Interesting. I found this SO question because I'm having the exact same issue, only with GitLab as my VCS integration. I'm using the same version you've listed there `Build 17015 15-Jan-2016 16:23` it shows in the bottom left corner of the dashboard. Is that what you have?

Comment: After searching here, I found a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-33655) confirming a fix, but it's not for the version mentioned here (although in your Bitbucket case it may have been). I can confirm that the issue is fixed in version 17031 with GitLab, however.